# Throwing exception while trying to send mail in tomcat 6.0.14 server

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, glassfish, jakarta-mail

```
  I have create a application in struts 2 which is sending mail to mail ids.
```

My problem is that while deploying my application on glassfish 3 server
   (on my local system) its sending mail properly.
      But when i am deploying my application on my actual server(using tomcat6.0.14) 
   its showing following exceptions

exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)...........
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
action.SendForgetPasswordAction.execute(SendForgetPasswordAction.java:117)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597).............
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
action.SendForgetPasswordAction.execute(SendForgetPasswordAction.java:117)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

How to resolve this problem i am uploading war file in my tomcat server

Comment: Make sure mail.jar is in your webapplication's lib directory. It is working in glassfish because the Java EE libraries that is bundled in Glassfish contain mail APIs.

Answer (score 1):

please add the mail.jar into the tomcat lib folder.. the issue being reported is for a class not being found (this class is available as part of the installation in GF but not in tomcat)

you could just copy the file from glassfish folder and place it in tomcat lib.

it will solve the issue.